# How do I calculate the centripetal force?

Tags: physics

In this experiment, a brown rubber weighs 42.2 grams and was spun at a velocity of 4.66m/s with a radius of 40cm and masses of 200g...the answer should be about 1.96N and I got 2.3.

Can someone confirm or deny this?

[image: Diagram of the experiment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same answer as you,
$$
F={mv^2\over r}=(42.2/1000)\times(4.66)^2/(40/100)=2.29{\rm Nm}
$$

Comment: Hey thanks for that, so the masses at the bottom - they don't count for anything in calculations?

Comment: If it's supposed to be in equilibrium the mass on the bottom times $g$ should equal the above.

Comment: Oh ok I see thank you :) most helpful.